# Transform Async Task method target framework 4.5 to TargetFramework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have SSO service that uses async `Task<ActionResult>` to get the URL

It works fine on my local environment but when I release on live I get following Error:

> Server Error in '/XXXX Application.
>
> "async void" Page events are unsupported in the current application
>   configuration. To enable this, set the following configuration switch
>   in Web.config:   
>    For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252465.

I have researched on this and apparently Async Task feature was developed for 4.0-4.5 .net framework. There was some different patterns or methodologies to do this in previous .net framework.

Comment: The obvious answer is to install the .NET 4.5 runtime. It's not just that emulating tasks is difficult. Asynchronous page events change the way ASP.NET loads a page to avoid blocking threads.

Comment: @dotctor the amount of work behind tasks and `async/await` is often underappreciated. You simply can't emulate them with some pattern or methodology. Page events in particular affect the way ASP.NET's pipeline works. Emulating asynchronous page events could mean rearchitecting the entire application eg to fork a background job, then wait on the client for some response.  Unless there is an important reason to run on an old framework version, it's not worth it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My only worry is as this is live environment and after installing .net 4.5 framework if the current services fails, is there a way to go back? I don't want the sites to be down for long period

Comment: .NET 4+ is a different distribution. You can have both 2.0 and 4+ on the same machine. In fact, side-by-side deployment is one of the major features of .NET 4

Comment: Page events are rather late in a request's lifecycle to perform authentication. What kind of SSO service are you using? There may be an ASP.NET authentication provider for it already, that works before the page even loads. Creating your own provider isn't hard either

Answer (score 2):

First prize would obviously to push for `.Net 4.5` to be installed or at least `.Net 4`. But since you're asking about `.Net 2`, this probably isn't an option.

If your call made to the server blocks until complete and the work on the server is async, you can make use of the [`Thread` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) to delegate work in different threads.

Here are some thoughts ways of achieving this:

**No return types, No parameters**

```
var ts = new ThreadStart(DoWorkAsync);
new Thread(ts).Start();
...  
public void DoWorkAsync()
{
   // This happens on a different thread.
}
```

**No return types, with parameters**

```
int id = 1;
var pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWorkWithParamsAsync);
new Thread(pts).Start(id);
...
public void DoWorkWithParamsAsync(object obj)
{
    // This happens on a different thread.
    int id = (int)obj;
}
```

**With return types (IAsyncResult)**

You could use the `BeginInvoke` method an then use a specific `delegate` signature with a return type:

```
Func<int> returnsIntDel = DoWorkReturnIntAsync;
var asyncRes = returnsIntDel.BeginInvoke(null, null);
//... some other work on main thread here...
int returnedInt = returnsIntDel.EndInvoke(asyncRes);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
...
public int DoWorkReturnIntAsync()
{
    // This happens on a different thread.
    return 0;
}
```

**Synchronizing between threads**

If you run into any synchronization scenarios where `Thread`s need to communicate or wait for each other, there are *Synchronization Primitive* class available for these scenarios (images from [filterdCode](https://filteredcode.wordpress.com/) blog).

- [ManualResetEventSlim](https://filteredcode.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/manualreseteventslim.png?w=375&h=396)
- [SemaphoreSlim](https://filteredcode.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/semaphoreslim.png?w=609&h=351)
- [CountdownEvent](https://filteredcode.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/countdownevent.png)
- [Barrier](https://filteredcode.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/barrier.png?w=809&h=553)

Comment: Note that the question is about asynchronous *page events* like loading.  When the Thread finishes its work there won't be anyone listening to process the results.

Comment: This won't help - once a web request finishes, there is no-one to monitor and receive results. If you want to use the thread's response (eg an authentication request) you'd have to block. In which case, you might as well make the blocking call anyway. IIS uses a separate thread to service each request so there is no need to spawn another thread.